# Unable to get data from RIA Service

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying the SL4 and RIA Services out. I followed the common tutorials available using SL4 Business template but I don't know why when I run the app I won't get any results from the service.

I have added a ADO.NET model which is connected to Northwind database and has only Employees table in it and also created its domain service.

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=employeeDomainDataSource, Path=Data}" />
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my1:Employee, CreateList=true}" Height="0" LoadedData="employeeDomainDataSource_LoadedData" Name="employeeDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetEmployeesQuery" Width="0">
                <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                    <my:NorthwindContext />
                </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Comment: Which type of control are you trying to bind the results to? A datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. My fault! I have not set the AutoGenerateColumns property to true